# Replacing HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html

As I'm working on big code, I'm wondering is there any possibilities replacing HTML with PHP code more easily so that for example `<?php $HelloWorld ?>` would become something like `--HelloWorld--` in the document? Or for example the loop would go from:

```
<?php 
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
} 
?>
```

To simplified string like

```
-(10)-{The number is: $x <br>}-
```

Comment: There are template libraries that can do things like this.

Comment: Maybe look into Smarty? http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: https://twig.sensiolabs.org/, http://www.smarty.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a templating engine.

Many if not all of the major php frameworks have a templating engine that gives you the possibility to use templates like this.

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) for example uses a templating engine called blade which enables you to write in blade syntax.

```
The number is {$x}
```

Or

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
 {$user->name} <br>
@endforeach
```

Or

```
@if(true)
 Do this
@else
 Else do that
@endif
```

Hope this helps